# Combining textures and UVs of a multiple objects into one

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking

I have a scene with many objects with separate materials with textures and UV maps. I need to combine all the textures into one large texture atlas ideally with the current UV maps to save me some work. Is this possible in Blender 2.8? I have found some tutorials for earlier versions where an addon called "Texture Atlas" was available, but this is not in 2.8 anymore.
I tried to create a blank picture and add a disconnected texture node to every material and then bake it in cycles, but the second object overwrites the textures from the first one.
Have I missed something or is this just not possible in 2.8 and I have to manually create the large texture and assign the UV maps again?

[image: combine textures]